# Jbrowserdriver within jar bundled as exe won't work

Tags: java, macos, selenium, jar, exe

I am working on a program for Windows and Mac. This program is using the Jbrowserdriver and Selenium libraries to access different websites and the websites' various "inputs" like buttons and text fields.

An example of the use can be seen here below:

```
JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().
                  timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK).build());

driver.get("http://website.com/example.php");

String webString = driver.findElement(By.id("divContainer")).getText();

System.out.println(webString);
```

Now here comes the issue, I have three different files:

1. The jar compiled into a Mac `.app`,
2. The regular `.jar` file,
3. The jar compiled into a Windows `.exe` file.

When running the Mac .app, it works with no issues at all. When running the .jar file on Mac there is no issue, and it works entirely. When running the .jar file on a Windows computer, there are no issues either, and it works as supposed. But whenever I run the .exe file on a Windows machine it opens the program, but at the function where I click a button, and it runs a JBrowserDriver function it "stalls" so to speak, it doesn't do anything at all.

This to me seems as if it is the JBrowserDriver which is the issue, but how come it works when just running it as a regular .jar but not when compiled into the .exe file? Am I missing something, or is this just not possible to do?

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: @Gintas_ I ended up just using the .jar file as an executable, I was never really able to make it work using the Windows .exe